# Select a value from drop-down list items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am  using a drop-down list in one of my templates.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LastName, Model.LastNames, new { id = "LastName" })
```

When drop-down list is displayed and if I want to pre-select any values from the items for drop-down list, how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you can set selected to true for the list of last names like so...

```
    List<SelectListItem> LastNames= new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "Jones",
          Value = "Jones"
        });
items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Smith",
            Value = "Smith",
            Selected = true
        });
items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Johnson",
            Value = "Johnson"
        });
```